# How to Authenticate user using Socketio-jwt node.js

Tags: node.js, performance, security, socket.io, jwt

I asked this question on [**Github socketio-jwt**](https://github.com/auth0/socketio-jwt/issues/75). 3 days later no answer, and couldnt find any answers on google either.

#### Question 1:

Is it secure enough to check token on connection? do I need to check token on every event?
E.g. check on every getNews event

```js
socket.on("getNews", function(data, callback){
// check token and if valid return news via callback
});
```

vs

Check on connection/reconnection

```js
io.use(function(socket, next) { // using general example not socketio-jwt
// check token and if valid proceed
});
```

#### Question 2:

how to know which user the particular token belongs to? One way would be to add id to payload, however, is it best practice?

Comment: so what you did? 
I am right now at the same situation that how to know that this request belongs to which user so that we can use appropriate SECRET_KEY (may be mixture of id+msisdn) to authenticate the user.

Comment: To be honest I don't remember what I did. But as far as I understand if you are using `wss://` you only need to check the token on connection and not on each event for WebSockets. Although, as far as I understand socket.io uses long poling, flash sockets, etc... in which case it is probably worth checking on every event.

Comment: For `id` you can use `io.engine.generateId` to change the id so you know which user belongs to which socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the token on every event, to make sure.

Yes, adding a user ID to your payload is fine-- as long as your secret stays secret.